# MSAL Library for Android took fairly long time to retrieve access token from cache

Tags: android, azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

Following the guidelines highlighted at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-acquire-cache-tokens , every time before I make an API call I'll first call acquireTokenSilentAsync to get the access token either from cache, or a new one automatically using the refresh token.

This works well, except that it seems to be quite slow in retrieving from cache. See below screenshot for timing:

[image]

As you can see when I just started the app, it manage to retrieve the access token used in the last run (I copied it out to a text file and compared) it took 2 seconds. Subsequently it became faster on each run, but it still take more than half a second to retrieve the exact same access token from cache. Loading from cache should take just about 5ms to 10ms?

This is my acquireTokenSilently implementation, just basic configuration.

```
private fun acquireTokenSilently(serviceName: String, callback: IAcquireTokenSilentlyCallback) {
        val parameters: AcquireTokenSilentParameters = AcquireTokenSilentParameters.Builder()
            .withScopes(authConfigReader.getServiceScopes(serviceName))
            .forAccount(firstAccount)
            .fromAuthority(authConfigReader.authorityUrl)
            .withCallback(object : SilentAuthenticationCallback {
                override fun onSuccess(authenticationResult: IAuthenticationResult) {
                    callback.onSuccess(authenticationResult.authorizationHeader)
                }

                override fun onError(exception: MsalException) {
                    callback.onError(mapMsalException(exception))
                }
            })
            .build()

        publicClientApp!!.acquireTokenSilentAsync(parameters)
    }
```

Do we need to write our own token persistence implementation like the one mentioned in the MSAL for Java section? This is not mentioned in the MSAL for Android section though:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-java-token-cache-serialization

Thanks!

Bruce